# Routing https in AWS beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk

I currently have an AWS BeanStalk setup.  I'm attempting to run my traffic through https.

In my beanstalk configuration I have my Document root set to `/public`.  This is because I'm running Laravel and the root path is public.
In Route 53 I have `example.com` being aliased to `mybeantsalk.url.here`.

All this works.  I can visit example.com and it points to my beanstalk.
However I added https by going to AWS Certificate.  In load balancer I have the following setting:

```
Port 80 • Protocol: HTTP • Instance port: 80 • Instance Protocol: HTTP
```

For https I have:

```
Port 443 • Protocol: HTTPS • Instance port: 80 • Instance Protocol: HTTP
```

When I visit https://example.com my site isn't loading all the css assets.  Also when I click on any item it goes to http://example.com not https.  How can I add a cert so it'll just work on my domain name?